# How to set background under ActionBar

Tags: android, background, android-actionbar

My mobile application must have background image for all space (activity). 
ActionBar is transparent and I want the background image to be seen through the ActionBar.
How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can make your action bar transparent by doing something like this :

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#330000ff")));
actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#550000ff")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this single line in your activity, after `setContentView()` call

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
```